# Is an unbiased estimator with arbitrarily small variance necessarily consistent?

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability, estimation-theory

Given an unbiased estimator $\hat \theta_n$ of a parameter $\theta$, if the estimator has small variance (approaching $0$ as $n\to\infty$), it seems reasonable to expect that the estimator is consistent (i.e. that $\hat \theta_n$  converges in probability to the constant $\theta$).

Is that actually true?

Comment: yes. it follows from Markov's inequality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markov's inequality says that for a non-negative random variable $X$ with expected value $\mu$,
$$
\Pr(X>a) \le \frac \mu a.
$$
(E.g. no more than $1/15$ of the population can have more than $15$ times the average income (assuming all incomes are non-negative), etc.)

So
$$
\Pr(|\hat \theta_n - \theta| > \varepsilon) = \Pr((\hat\theta_n-\theta)^2>\varepsilon^2)
\le \frac{\sigma_n^2}{\varepsilon^2} \to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty
$$
where $\sigma_n^2=\operatorname{var}(\hat\theta_n)$.